# Normal curvature of a circle in a plane

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I have the circle $\gamma(t) = (\cos t, \sin t, 0)$ in the plane $z=0$.

Now I understand that normal curvature is related to the second fundamental form, and an expression for it is $\kappa_n=L\dot{u}^2 + 2M\dot{u}\dot{v} + N\dot{v}^2$, where, if there is a surface patch $\sigma(u,v)$, then $L=\sigma_{uu}\cdot \vec{N}, M=\sigma_{uv}\cdot \vec{N}, N=\sigma_{vv} \cdot \vec{N}$ where $\vec{N}$ is the normal vector to the surface.

I assume that the surface patch for a plane $z=0$ is $\sigma(u,v)=(u,v,0)$. So $\sigma_{uu}=\sigma_{uv}=\sigma_{vv}=0$, and so $L=M=N=0$ thus $\kappa_n=0$

I am looking for verification that my answer is correct.

Also, apparently if the normal curvature is equal to zero, the curve is called asymptotic. Can I then say that this curve $\gamma$ on $\sigma$ is indeed asymptotic?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't you have a definition the curvature of a *curve*?

Answer (score 0):

Start with something non-trivial for a surface. There should be *two* parameters $(u,v)$.

$\gamma(u,v) = (\cos u, \sin u, v)$ where u =constant are generators of a cylinder and v = constant are circles projected on x,y plane.
Now evaluate normal curvature as you did; the v= constant parameter lines have circles of  $\kappa_n$ = 1. For u = constant parameter lines $\kappa_n$ is zero and can indeed be viewed as asymptotic, but that is also trivial along these prismatic lines.

For a better understanding of normal curvature $\kappa_n$ Euler's theorem helps to determine them with reference to the  $(u,v)$ parameter grid.

An asymptotic line always divides the negative Gauss curvature surface into four   pairwise vertically opposite placed $\kappa_n$ positive and negative  regions.

As a further exercise please repeat the procedure for the helicoid:

$\gamma(u,v) = (u  \cos v, u \sin v, v)$ ; it will be evident that quadrants 1 and 3 have positive  $\kappa_n$ while quadrants 2 and 4 have negative  $\kappa_n$.